# Delete/Destroy is not working within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get a delete button to work using a piece of code I have written within my tags_controller page;

```
  def destroy
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @tag.destroy

    redirect_to :back, notice: 'Tag was successfully deleted!'
  end
```

When I run from my local host, it throws an exception as shown below;

```
Routing Error
No route matches [DELETE] "/admin/tags/37/edit"

Rails.root: /Users/laurenwoodhams/Desktop/PROJECT/RAILS-BLOG/-t
```

Here is my config routes;

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get '/login' => 'admin/sessions#new'
get '/logout' => 'admin/sessions#destroy'

namespace :admin do
    resources :posts
    resources :tags, except: [:index]
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :administrators, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
end
end
```

Could you please examine and explain why this may be occurring?

Thank you

Comment: You need to make the delete to `/admin/tags/37/`, not `/admin/tags/37/edit`

Comment: Does your controller include a `before_filter` that sets the `Tag` object for your `destroy` method? Do you actually have a `DELETE` route for your `Tag` objects? Post the portion of your `config/routes.rb` file that covers actions associated with `Tag`.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, please see the portion of my config routes file within my edited post.

Comment: @TheSuper, where do I change this?

Comment: This looks odd... Are you calling delete via a `link_to`? Can you post that? Also, add 'puts "destroy method id = #{params[:id]}' as the first line in your destroy method and run again. I'm wondering whether you're passing junk data to the destroy method.

Comment: Could you show your view file please?

Answer (score 0):

**DELETE** is the HTTP verb (like GET or POST) which means..

To make a link to delete your tag you'll need to do something like this in your view.

```
<%= link_to "Delete Tag", @tag, method: "delete" %>
```

Then it should work properly.

P.S.
You can run `bin/rake routes` to see your routes.